# Google Cloud Platform free trial billing

Tags: cloud, free, platform, trial, google-cloud-billing

I activated Google Cloud Platform free trial.
I keep receiving  monthly invoices for no amount.
I cancelled all projects.
If I cancel my Billing account will I be charged of previous invoices even if  I am in my free trial period ?

I apoloigize for the question but it is not clear from google support.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have a valid Payments Account linked to your Billing Account, you will be charged for outstanding balances. Since you are under the Free Trial and your statements have a zero balance, you have no payments due. If you are concerned that you will be charged for services used under the Free Trial by cancelling early, that will not happen.

To check if you have a balance and to review previous invoices go to your [Billing Account](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/). In the right side look for "Promotional credits. This will let you know how much credit you have left. In the left panel click on Documents. You will see a list of monthly statements and Amounts. In the left panel click on Transactions. This will show your "Ending Balance" and any charges due.

I recommend that you delete the Project. Go to IAM & Admin -> Manage Resources. You can delete the project in this panel.

Go back to the Billing Account. Select Account Management. You can delete the Billing account on this page.

You will have one final account, the Payments Account. This is located in the [Google Payments Center](http://%20https://payments.google.com/). This is where your credit card is tied to Google to pay invoices. This account is used to pay for anything you purchase from Google such as Google Cloud, YouTube, YouTube TV, Google Ads, Google Store, etc.